# Ошибка миграции Django, Data truncated for column 'id'

Tags: python, mysql, django

Создал модель

```
class PaymentOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    summ = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Заявка на пополнение %s от %s' % (self.user, self.date)
```

Создаю миграции python manage.py makemigration
Миграции создаются

Когда делаю python manage.py migrate получаю ошибку:

```
File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.DataError: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 572, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 726, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/var/www/invest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.DataError: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1")
```

Пытался создать вручную поле id:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=1)
```

Такая же ошибка
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: В модели были уже данные? Или это новая модель?

Answer (score 0):

Django выдает ошибку о том что в какой то таблице изначально был столбец id, а теперь нет. Это может быть таблицы стандартные которое создает django.
Вам нужно полностью очистить базу данных (если она у вас стандартная то нужно удалить файл 'db.sqlite3') и удалить все файлы миграции. Они находиться в папке {папка с названием приложения}/migrations. Файлов миграции может быть несколько, они имеют вид: '0001_initial.py' или '0003_auto_20200812_2247.py'. Надо удалить все кроме файла **init**.py.И так в каждом приложение. После этого нужно сделать

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо удалить миграционные файлы Django. Вы можете найти их в папке `migrations` в директории того приложения, где вы создавали эту модель. **Вам не обязательно удалить миграции из других приложений, если они корректно работали.** Затем отчистите таблицы в базе данных.

Что бы вам сильно не страдать с языком SQL, просто удалите базу данных. Если вы используете sqlite3, то удалите файл бд, если Postgres – используйте команду консоли postgres `DROP DATABASE db_name;`. Команды удаления для остальных БД найдете в поисковике корпорации добра. **Вы должны понимать, что потеряете все данные которые были в БД**. Если для вас это неприемлемо, воспользуйтесь командой `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;` в консоли бд. Эта строчка проверит таблицу на существование перед удалением.

После этого снова создайте необходимые таблицы и примените миграции:

```bsh
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Не забудьте создать суперпользователя, если вы его создавали ранее.

```bsh
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Ваш первоначальный код работает:

```py
class PaymentOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    summ = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Заявка на пополнение %s от %s' % (self.user, self.date)
```

[image: вывод консоли]